# Array reduce : Sum total of Array length in within another array

Tags: arrays, reduce, reselect

I am having difficulty calculating the total votes from the array of choices . I have a json like below

```
 {
    id:1,
    pollName: 'aaaaa',
    pollChoices:[
    id: 2,
    choice : 'dddd',
    votes: [
     {

     }
    ]
  ]
 }
```

I am trying to count the total number votes casted from the jon above within my memoized [selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

My code is like below

```
const pollChoices: Array<PollChoice> = poll.get("PollChoices").toJS();
            const pollStatistic = pollChoices
               .reduce((prev: any, curr: any) => {
                console.log("The pollStatistic is ", prev);
                return { curr, totalVotesCasted: (prev.Votes ? 
                  (prev.Votes.length + curr.Votes.length) : 
                   0 + curr.Votes.length )}
            }, {});

 console.log("The pollStatistic is ", pollStatistic);
```

The console within `pollStatistic` seems to show my totalVotesCasted, however, when i print `pollStatistic`, its always undefined, i want to be able to get the pollStatistic.totalCount in my state. Pls any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works. 
You pass the reduce function a reducer callback of this signature: `function reducer(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) { ... }`

The callback should return a the value of the accumulator it wants to be passed to the next iteration.
In your case when you access `prev.Votes` you should be accessing `prev.totalVotesCasted` which is the value you set on the accumulator.